# Can you run or debug a SQL Server stored procedure without side effects?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I would like to be able to see the effects of running a Stored Procedure that someone else has written or other SQL code on a production database, in order to debug it. I would like to be able to see the updated values in the table without it actually affecting their data.

Is there a way that I would be able to see these changes in this way?

Comment: Loads of ways, debug print, debug select, rollback transaction etc etc... test database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
/*SQL code here */
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

This will allow you to test changes without committing them to the database.

You can read more about this in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Remember to do any investigative queries inside the transaction as outside of it the changes will revert.
You could also create a testing database too by cloning an existing one, then you can test without worry!

Answer (score 0):

Create a SQL Server database project in VS, add a script file, paste the SQL code which you want to debug inside this block

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
/*SQL code here */
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Then you can use all the debug functionality of VS.